# Is there a tool for monitoring WCF queues?

Tags: wcf, monitor

Is there any tool for monitoring incoming and outgoing calls from a WCF service?

I do not mean MSMQ, I mean queued calls that the service is not able to handle cause of it is busy.

Some profile for Performance monitor perhaps?

Kind Regards
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WCF hosted on IIS you can use [ASP.NET performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx) to see number of queued requests, current requests etc. for example:

- **ASP.NET\Requests Queued**
- **Web Service\Current Connections**

Although WCF has a lot of [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms750527%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) available, there is none indicating queues length.

If you are talking about queued messages content, there is no easy way. The only I can think of is taking a full memory dump of the process and investigating it. But this is of course very intrusive, single shot task.